# $_SESSION gets unset before accessing value

Tags: php

Code for setting the session message

```
if($result === true) {
$session->message('The admin was updated successfully');
// $_SESSION['message'] = 'The admin was updated successfully';
redirect_to(url_for('/staff/admins/show.php?id=' . $id));
  } else {
   // show errors
  }
```

This is the code for displaying the session message

```
function display_session_message() {
  global $session;
  $msg = $session->message();
  if(isset($msg) && $msg != '') {
    $session->clear_message();
    return '<div id="message">' . $msg . '</div>';
  }
}
```

Code for getting session message

```
   public function message($msg="") {
    if (!empty($msg)) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = $msg;
        return true;
    } else {
        return $_SESSION['message'] ?? '';
    }
  }
```

Session Class (also included in this class is `public function message()`)

```
class Session 
{
     public function __construct() {
         session_start();
         $this->check_stored_login();
  }
     public function clear_message() {
         unset($_SESSION['message']);
  }
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: In the code for displaying the session message, the $_SESSION['message'] gets unset before being accessed @u_mulder

Comment: What happens when you comment out `$session->clear_message();`?

Comment: It works and displays the session message@zeitnot

Answer (score 1):

You have to use:

```
session_start();
```

in top of each file you are using for session to work

Comment: simple but correct.  the op isn't starting the session via `session_start()`.  Also shouldn't be using `global`.

Comment: @ivanivan, how do you know?  The op only posted a snippet.  This answer makes assumptions that shouldn't have been made without getting clarifications.

Comment: @Devon without seeing it in a "minimal complete example", how do you know the OP is doing it?

Comment: @ivanivan, is that your serious evaluation of a correct answer?  Especially based on the OP's update, this answer was incorrect.  That's why large assumptions like this are entirely off base for an answer.